# Libgdx Scrolling TiledMaps

Tags: java, android, libgdx

i'm trying to make my libgdx map scroll, but i dont know the code to make map scroll, please guys help me, i would like the map to scroll like flappy bird game, this is my my code which show the map on the screen

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    position.y = position.y - 4;

    if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
        position.y = position.y +10;
    }

    if(position.y < 0){
        position.y = 0;
    }

    if(position.y > Gdx.graphics.getHeight() -70){
        position.y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 70;
    }

    renderer.setView(camera);
    renderer.render();

//tells the computer when to start drawing textures
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(Green1, position.x, position.y, 50, 50);
    batch.end();

}

@Override
public void show() {
    Green1 = new Texture("img/Green1.png");
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    position = new Vector2(20, Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    map = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/map1.tmx");

    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
}

@Override
public void hide() {


}

@Override
public void create() {
    Green1 = new Texture("img/Green.png");
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    position = new Vector2(20, Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    camera.viewportWidth = width;
    camera.viewportHeight = height;
    camera.position.set(width/2f, height/3f, 0); //by default camera position on (0,0,0)
    camera.update();
}

@Override
public void render() {


}

@Override
public void pause() {


}

@Override
public void resume() {


}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    map.dispose();
    renderer.dispose();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When I was learning to build 2D games I used star-assault for an example. You can find their github repository here: https://github.com/chrismorales/2d-sidescroller && https://github.com/chrismorales/2d-sidescroller/blob/master/star-assault/src/net/obviam/starassault/view/WorldRenderer.java should be useful to look at.